# Physics of Balls in Sphere, with rotating arms

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have some sort of Bingo Wheel and want to make animation of Balls rotating in it. Balls are supposed to bounce in wheel, and those, I will call them "Arms" are constantly rotating so I want balls to interact with them, and with edges of spheres.

I added rigid body > passive > collision (mesh) to sphere, and duplicated it and did same to that new sphere because balls were going outside of sphere if there is only one. Also, added rigid body > passive > collision to those hands, to make them interact with balls.
But somehow I feel something is missing since they are always moving in same direction.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you meant your arms. You rotated them only on one axis.

Just rotate them both on all axis with different values.

e.g. frame 0:

[image]

frame 25:

[image]

keyframe that values, press Shift-E and choose linear extrapolation.

result: (sorry, that i was lazy, i just rotated one arm on all axis)

[image]